# how to switch image on slidepanellayout in android

Tags: android

how to use image to show more & less in slidepanellayout in android.i am using demo application from this link,check this layout.xml 
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/master/demo/res/layout/activity_demo.xml 
if data hidden it has to show down icon & and when it expanded it has to show up icon